# Infinite groups admitting field structure

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

Does every **infinitely** generated Abelian group admit a field structure?
(i.e. If $(G,+)$ is an infinitely generated Abelian group, then,
is there a binary operation "$\cdot$" such that $(G,+,\cdot)$ is a field?)

Is there any **characterization** (or classification) of such these groups
(admitting field structure) ?

(What about Abelian groups admitting ring structure with nontrivial multiplication?)

Answer (score 9):

A field is a vector space over its prime field, so its additive group is either a group of prime exponent $p$, or a torsion-free divisible group, depending on the characteristic. Conversely, any such abelian group is an additive group of an extension of $\mathbb F_p$ or $\mathbb Q$ of appropriate degree.

Comment: Emil: your answer just provides the explanation of my counterexample.

Answer (score 5):

No. Consider for instance the direct product of all groups of distinct prime order.

Answer (score 1):

This question is discussed already in MO and  you can find the answer in the links below:

1- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154852/a-basic-question-about-rings/154882#154882

2- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154964/is-every-commutative-group-structure-underlying-at-least-one-unitary-commutati/154979#154979

3- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155179/potentially-identity-elements-in-an-abelian-group